# editing a json object with Jansson APIs

Tags: c, jansson

I am using jansson library, I am want to edit a Json object, how can I do this, do I have to use any specific API ??
Spare me if this question is repeated .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us the code you have so far and tell us what you want to achieve. Latest [Jansson API Reference can be found here](https://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/2.12/apiref.html)

Comment: @Gerhardh thanks for reference . I used the APIs and helped me to make my code work